# Modal Popup Detection Utility (.NET or PowerShell)

Tags: c#, powershell

Does any one know how do I get the current open windows or dialogs through either PowerShell or C#?

We have a lot of automated processes running, especially at night, and occasionally one of these gets blocked by an open dialog waiting for human intervention.  In a perfect world, I would design my apps so this would never happen but the problem is with third party applications that I just have to live with.

I don't want to close the window but but would like to be alerted to its presence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider leveraging [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) to find all top-level windows on the screen. It may be necessary to pair that with some more details to better understand if there is a dialog. For example the dialog might always come from a specific process.

In order to integrate the `EnumWindows` function in C# you can leverage a couple of types.

**Interop**

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/// <remarks>https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8c5260061b11323dfd97fbab614d54402405513f/src/Common/src/Interop/Windows/User32/Interop.EnumWindows.cs#L8</remarks>
internal partial class Interop
{
    internal partial class User32
    {
        internal delegate bool EnumThreadWindowsCallback(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumThreadWindowsCallback callback, IntPtr extraData);
    }
}
```

**Sample Call**

```cs
Interop.User32.EnumThreadWindowsCallback callback = new Interop.User32.EnumThreadWindowsCallback(
    (topLevelWindow, param) => {
        // TODO do work with IntPtr topLevelWindow

        return true; // Return false if you want to stop enumeration early.
    }
);
Interop.User32.EnumWindows(callback, IntPtr.Zero);

GC.KeepAlive(callback);
```

I have another use of this function implemented in an app I built [quick-windows](https://github.com/joncloud/quick-windows/blob/8c8435eb6ff88f1f1ca7f52c6fdd237f1cdec6b9/src/QuickWindows/AllWindowsFinder.cs#L15-L22).